# Significance of Polygamy?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the *Wheel Of Time* series, polygamy is significant not only to the main character's story arc, but also an entire culture (the Aiel).

**What is its significance?**

My girlfriend is convinced that it's just some old guy's fantasy, not an important plot point. I feel like Robert Jordan wouldn't have included it if there weren't a deeper meaning, but I haven't found anything to really explain it.

Are there any interviews with Robert Jordan, his wife Hariet, or Brandon Sanderson that even allude to the inclusion of this phenomenon? Is it a reference to any particular culture out of universe?

If there is no such reference for the Aiel culture in general, what about Rand in particular? He ends up loving three women. Is this part of the story pulled from any specific legends/myths? Does it tie into the plot in any central way? It's interesting that there are also three central ta'veren, but that could be mere coincidence.

Comment: well jordan is clearly a little sexist, but alot of cultures have polygamy and he included alot of cultures in his righting

Comment: @Himarm Sexist in which direction?

Comment: @CHEESE - all of them, I think.

Comment: I dont really have an answer as to what Robert Jordan intended however I cant agree that the polygamy depicted is in anyway sexist since IIRC both Aiel men and women were free to have multiple wives and husbands

Comment: @revenant Are you sure about that? I don't remember any Aiel women having multiple husbands.

Comment: *"just some old-guy's fantasy, not an important plot point. I feel like Robert Jordan wouldn't have included it if there weren't a deeper meanings"* It doesn't have to be either. Polygamy is a thing that exists.

Comment: I'm kinda tempted to just vote to close, as this is either opinion or too broad without the author to ask.  That said, I'm also curious as to the point of the question.  Robert Jordan is somewhat known for Frankensteining various cultures in this series, so including polygamy isn't farfetched.  Polygamy does exist, both as cultural standard and individual choice, as serious relationship commitment or as male testosterone symptom / oppression tool, depending on what exactly you're talking about.  Which deeper meaning are you looking for, or which shallower implication is being avoided here?

Comment: @Rand al'Thor I could be mistaken but I seem to remember one of the wise women making a reference to her second husband although its possible the conversation was actually in reference to her husbands second wife

Comment: The significance may well be that Robert Jordan seems to like to put the characters in culture clash situations.

Comment: There *is* an Aes Sedai near the end of *Crossroads Of Twilight* who is rumored to marry "all her warders", so it's not *entirely* about men marrying multiple women.

Comment: I think any answer to this question would be pure speculation. I like to think that RJ included the polygamy just to accentuate the cultural differences of the Aiel to the other races. Rand is, afterall, Aiel, so why shouldn't he adhere to their traditions? If you think of it this way, then I find reasonable justification for its inclusion above the author/reader self-insert sex fantasy.

Comment: You even see it take place on the page. In tSR, the Wise One, Melaine, expresses to fellow Wise One, Dorindha, she loves Dorindha's husband Bael, and Dorindha gives her blessing to become sister wives. She runs off right then to lay a bridal wreath at the feet of an already married man, and then in tLoC it's revealed she's pregnant with his twins.

Answer (score -3):

The point is that Rand was the Dragon Reborn - a character so important to history (his original sealed the Dark One's prison, causing all male One Source-users to go mad with the counterattack and founding the Aes Sedai), that many women would want to be part of his life, to marry him.  So Rand had to live up to the expectations of history of the Dragon Reborn, and women trying to become part of the Dragon Reborn's life for the power it would give them, for love, etc.  Don't forget that several kingdoms in the lands were promised to the Dragon Reborn, should he return, and thus Rand became embroiled in political intrigues.

It's important to the plot of Wheel of Time because to control Rand would be to have some control over The Final Battle for that person's group - Aes Sedai, a kingdom, the desert dwellers, etc.  Several people wanted to make sure Rand would spare their family or kingdom from The Final Battle, just in case.  And let the Wheel of Time roll on again afterwards.

Personally I believe it is believable that a person like Rand, so pivotal to history, would have women trying to marry him for that sole reason.

Comment: None of the women who end up loving him do so for personal gain. It doesn't add up as an explanation.